# Column value replacement based on duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

In my dataset, I have the `OrderID` column and `OrderTotal` column.

I have duplicate `OrderID`s. I don't want to remove the duplicates, instead, I want to keep the values of order total with the first instance of `OrderID` and replace the value of `OrderTotal` to 0 when there are other duplicates for `OrderID`.

Here is what I have done:

```
duplicate=df.OrderID.duplicated(keep='first')
df['OrderTotal']=np.where((duplicates =='True'), 0 ,df['OrderTotal'])
```

I am having this error:

> usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py:253: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
> res_values = method(rvalues)

Comment: What is the problem with what you have?

Comment: Its not producing the result, producing an error

Comment: Which error? Please [edit] the question and show the error including the full traceback.

Comment: it should not have any problem if you change ```'True'``` to ```True```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d={'OrderID':['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','d','d'],
    'OrderTotal':[2355, 1546,987,2451, 571,3859,1876, 1239,2836,2395]}
data=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
print(data)
   OrderID  OrderTotal
0        a        2355
1        a        1546
2        a         987
3        b        2451
4        b         571
5        c        3859
6        c        1876
7        c        1239
8        d        2836
9        d        2395
```

## Using numpy.where()

```
duplicates=data['OrderID'].duplicated(keep='first')
data['OrderTotal']=np.where((duplicates==True), 0 ,data['OrderTotal'])
```

## Using DataFrame.where()

```
duplicates=data['OrderID'].duplicated(keep='first')
data['OrderTotal']=data['OrderTotal'].where(duplicates== False, 0)
```

Updated dataframe for both cases,

```
print(data)
   OrderID  OrderTotal
0        a        2355
1        a           0
2        a           0
3        b        2451
4        b           0
5        c        3859
6        c           0
7        c           0
8        d        2836
9        d           0
```